Wireshark not working when monitoring btsnoop, throwing timestamp error
I am trying to monitor bluetooth traffic from an old android phone (LineageOS, android 7.1.2) using wireshark. I am following a tutorial here, under the "Getting live bt_snoop data with Wireshark" section. I have the phone connected, Bluetooth HCI snoop log is enabled, and adb root running. Wireshark seems to be working too, until I do anything that sends a bluetooth packet, at which point it promptly throws the following error:
An error occurred while writing to the file "\\.\pipe\wireshark_extcap_android-bluetooth-btsnoop-net-42004ff5ca5b5300_20240530131643": We don't support writing that record's time stamp to that file type.

It then shows the following info box:
No packets captured.

As no data was captured, closing the temporary capture file.

Help about capturing can be found at

       https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/wikis/CaptureSetup

Wireless (Wi-Fi/WLAN):
Try to switch off promiscuous mode in the Capture Options.

and stops the capture. As far as I can tell, this is an issue with how the HCI snoop log records timestamps, but beyond that I have no idea. I have looked all over the internet for even a mention of this error, but I have gotten nothing. Any help would be appreciated. Cheers.

So, just for future reference if anyone else runs into this problem, I did some further digging and found the solution.
So, tracing back the error, I found where it was being thrown within the wireshark code:
if (rec->ts.secs < 0 || rec->ts.secs > INT32_MAX) {
    *err = WTAP_ERR_TIME_STAMP_NOT_SUPPORTED;
    return false;
}

Basically, if the timestamp is less than 0, or greater than the max 32-bit int, it throws this error and stops. So, the solution is the dumbest thing imaginable: set your clock back on the device you are capturing to 1970. This brings the timestamp back within legal limits, and everything works.

Nice find.  I am curious though - the current seconds since epoch is 1,717,081,130 which is less than a signed 32-bit integer maximum.  Is it the case your device clock could just be set to current time?

@Computable I don't think so. I did some testing, out of curiosity, and found it was around December 20th 2023 that it breaks, and the timestamp reads around 2147483, about a thousand times less than INT32_MAX. My theory is that whatever weird time stamp system LineageOS is using, Wireshark is interpreting it as seconds, converting it to milliseconds, and then some bug is causing that millisecond value to be treated as seconds again. Again, I am no expert on any of this, that is just my theory
